# I tried to reproduce the "get-dimensions" script from the Puppeteer website locally

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

And this is what I got when I ran the program.

[Running get-dimensions in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVd6C.png)

How to get "height:" and "devicescalefactor:" to also print?

[Pauls Nodejs repo](https://github.com/paulgureghian/Nodejs_Programs/blob/master/Puppeteer/src/get-dimensions.js)

Comment: Hi Paul this might be related to the terminal. The code you linked exactly behaves correctly and there is nothing wrong with it. The output is  ```Dimensions: { width: 800, height: 600, deviceScaleFactor: 1 }```

Comment: Yup. I have since tried another terminal program and it worked as intended. 

Thanks.